# Convert ldif to json

Tags: java, json, ldif

I have an ldif file like,

`dn: cn=abn,o=kb
changetype:c
objectclass: a
objectclass: f
objectclass: v
objectclass: f
objectclass: hh
objectclass: kll
mail: s
surname: kg
givenname: fg
cn: kl`

`dn: cn=abn,o=kb
changetype:c
objectclass: a
objectclass: f
objectclass: v
mail: s
fullname : 87
surname: kg
givenname: fg
cn: kl`

and so on

Is there some library or script to convert this to json.

Comment: I have not found a lib. but can help with converter. could you provide expected json format for above file?

Comment: Thank you for your response `[{"dn":"abc","objectclass":["hghg","ghg","hg"]},{},{}]`  basically an array of json

Comment: I spent some time wrote a script for myself. it works alright.